# Search AD users through Cognito in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, active-directory, amazon-cognito, adfs, aws-userpools

I have Cognito setup to authenticate ADFS users. The Cognito's user pool is empty for now. All users and roles reside in AD. In this case, is it possible to list or search users from Active Directory (AD) by using the Cognito API in Spring Boot? If not, is there any approach to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't list Microsoft Active Directory (AD) users via Cognito APIs.

They're designed to interact directly with the user pools *in* Cognito, not with various federated identity providers like MSFT AD.

In Java, take a look at using the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview), [for Java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java) and the provided [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/administrativeunit-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#example-1-list-member-objects) on how to list members:

```java
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

DirectoryObjectCollectionWithReferencesPage members = graphClient.directory().administrativeUnits("8a07f5a8-edc9-4847-bbf2-dde106594bf4").members()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```